# Create QLabel besides the constructor

Tags: c++, qt

I have a vector of labels, declared in the `MainWindow` class:

```
QVector<QPointer<QLabel>> labels;
```

And a function:

```
void MainWindow::testFunc()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        labels.push_back(QPointer<QLabel>(new QLabel(this)));
        labels.back()->setGeometry(QRect(50 * i, 0, 50, 50));
        labels.back()->setText("test");
    }
}
```

I call this function in the class constuctor and everything is fine:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    testFunc();
}
```

Then I added a button and a connecting:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::testFunc);
}
```

And after clicking the labels aren't shown. I checked via debugger and in the both ways the labels are created and constructors for them are executed. Also I tried simple pointers, `QTimer::singleShot()` and `QPointer<QLabel>` without `QVector` - the result is the same.
Why the second way does't work? Why I can add a `QLabel` only in the constuctor?

Comment: Your `QMainWindow` should have a `centralWidget` and all widgets e.g. labels should be children of that central widget or its layout. Try calling `new QLabel(centralWidget())`.

Comment: @ypnos The same. In constuctor works, outside - no

Comment: if you set a breakpoint on testfunc, and you click pushbutton, the breakpoint gets triggered ?

Comment: @user Yes......

Comment: Could you edit your question with the constructor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QMainWindow alwayd should have a centralWidget that contains other chilrens. when using forms, centralWidget is automaticly created. you may manage labels in a horizontal layout and then add them to the centralWidget:

```
    QPointer<QHBoxLayout> hBoxLayout (new QHBoxLayout);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        labels.push_back(QPointer<QLabel>(new QLabel));
        labels.back()->setGeometry(QRect(50 * i, 0, 50, 50));
        labels.back()->setText("test");

        hBoxLayout->addWidget(labels.back().data());
    }
    ui->centralwidget->setLayout(hBoxLayout);
```